# Least cost path_routing

Tags: qgis, raster, routing, cost-path, network-analysis

I am using the Least-Cost-Path plugin tool to generate least cost routes using a given road raster layer...The thing is that the routes sometimes are irrational. For example, making a u-turn just because pixels are connected where actually connected pixels resemble a grade-separated intersection.

How can I avoid this? Or is there another tool that can do routing with a cost parameter (which is not distance)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not "irrational" for a least cost path to follow where pixels are connected.

Comment: What is the name of the tool you are using? I cant find any named **least cost path**

Comment: @BERA I believe the plugins' name is "Least-Cost Path"

Comment: @Alaa Torkey If you want better control over the "allowed" routes you should use a road **vector** layer which is able to handle both overlaps and direction in a way that raster cannot.